# no such device 656e7ebc

Tags: lubuntu

Can someone help me? I installed and ran lubuntu 19.10 from my USB stick which I lost and now am having trouble getting into windows. When I try to boot into windows it says:

```
No such device: 656e7ebc-c73f-40d4-81d0-7c3afcb2da54
Unkown filesystem
Entering rescue mode
```

Also I'm completely new to Linux so did I f something up

Comment: `sudo parted --list` please. Edit your question for output.

Answer (score 0):

I installed and ran boot repair and that fixed it